# How to show $d(Tx,Ty) \geq d(x,y)-d(x,Tx)-d(y,Ty)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, inequality, metric-spaces

I'm reading a proof that has this inequality which I figure follows somehow from the triangle ineq. but I can't figure it out.

I can provide more details if needed but I don't want to write out the whole proof, am I missing something simple here?

Comment: Add $d(x,Tx)+d(y,Ty)$ on both sides, and then use the triangle inequality twice, to collapse the path $x \to Tx \to Ty \to y$ into $x \to y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another way to write$$d(x,y)\leq d(x,Tx)+d(Tx,Ty)+d(Ty,y),$$which is simply the triangle inequality applied twice.